# How to map OneToOne recursion entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, recursion

I'm looking for how to solve a recursion and bidiretional onetoone relationship in my Branch object:

```
@Entity
@Table("BRANCH")
public class Branch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Branch parent;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Branch child;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

Is it an accepted pattern?

Comment: You should not have any problems with lazy initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way of bidirectional @OneToOne mapping with self reference:

```
@Entity
@Table("BRANCH")
public class Branch {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Branch parent;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
private Branch child;
```

- this is ancestor for object in child field
- this is descendant for object in parent field
- Hierarchy is: parent > this > child

> You do not require two foreign keys, single
>   foreign key in the owning side of the relationship is sufficient. In
>   JPA the inverse OneToOne must use the mappedBy attribute.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Inverse_Relationships,_Target_Foreign_Keys_and_Mapped_By